# XSLT transform output shows only 1st page and graph is cut off

Tags: html, xml, xslt

So I applied XSLT to XML code and had it show the output I needed,

the full XML code is shown but when I print it as html/pdf only the 1st page is shown and the bottom is cut off.

Does anyone know why it's not showing?

for reference this is my XSLT code

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="svg-width" select="1200"/>
    <xsl:variable name="svg-height" select="900"/>
    <xsl:variable name="max-bar-length" select="$svg-width - 400"/>

    <xsl:variable name="bar-height" select="20"/>
    <xsl:variable name="bar-spacing" select="50"/>
    <xsl:variable name="bar-start" select="200"/>

    <xsl:variable name="bar-width1" select="gdp_agri"/>
    <xsl:variable name="bar-width2" select="gdp_ind"/>
    <xsl:variable name="bar-width3" select="gdp_serv"/>
    <xsl:variable name="gdp_agri" select="gdp_agri"/>
    <xsl:variable name="gdp_ind" select="gdp_ind"/>
    <xsl:variable name="gdp_serv" select="gdp_serv"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <svg viewBox="0 0 {$svg-width} {$svg-height}" width="{$svg-width}px" height="{$svg-height}px">
                    <g id="bar-chart" font-size="16" transform="translate(20,100)">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::mondial/child::country[child::encompassed[attribute::continent='europe']]">
                         <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="name"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="country">
        <xsl:variable name="bar-width" select="gdp_agri"/>
        <g id="bar_{position()}" transform="translate(0, {(position() - 1) * ($bar-height + $bar-spacing)})">
            <text x="0" y="{($bar-height + $bar-spacing) div 2}">
                <xsl:number format="1. " value="position()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </text>
            <rect x="{$bar-start}" y="0" width="{$bar-width}" height="{$bar-height}" fill="green"/>
            <text x="{$bar-width +$bar-start + 5}" y="{0.2*($bar-height + $bar-spacing) div 2}">Agri GDP: <xsl:value-of select="gdp_agri"/>%</text>
        </g>
        
         <xsl:variable name="bar-width2" select="gdp_ind"/>
        <g id="bar_{position()}" transform="translate(0, {(position() - 1) * ($bar-height + $bar-spacing)})">
            <text x="0" y="{($bar-height + $bar-spacing) div 2}">
                <xsl:number format="1. " value="position()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </text>
            <rect x="{$bar-start}" y="20" width="{$bar-width2}" height="{$bar-height}" fill="brown"/>
            <text x="{$bar-width2 +$bar-start + 5}" y="{($bar-height + $bar-spacing) div 2}">Ind GDP: <xsl:value-of select="gdp_ind"/>%</text>
        </g>
        
        <xsl:variable name="bar-width3" select="gdp_serv"/>
        <g id="bar_{position()}" transform="translate(0, {(position() - 1) * ($bar-height + $bar-spacing)})">
            <text x="0" y="{($bar-height + $bar-spacing) div 2}">
                <xsl:number format="1. " value="position()"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
            </text>
            <rect x="{$bar-start}" y="40" width="{$bar-width3}" height="{$bar-height}" fill="yellow"/>
            <text x="{$bar-width3 +$bar-start + 5}" y="{($bar-height + $bar-spacing) div 1.2}">Serv. GDP: <xsl:value-of select="gdp_serv"/>%</text>
        </g>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply the transform later, it runs however only the first page of the output is shown. The rest of the countries that I'm running do not appear (this is the mondial database); they appear in the XML output but not when I print as html / pdf or even in the exist-DB output
[image: As can be seen there's more countries below but the html output doesn't show it though the full XML output does on ExistDB]

Comment: Well SVG isn't flowing content and your's is 900px tall.

Comment: this is not an eXist-db specific question

Answer (score 0):

You are building one big image, try to split that up so pagebreaks can be applied. I can only guess how that would work because you didn't share the xml data. Should be like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::mondial/child::country[child::encompassed[attribute::continent='europe']]">
                <xsl:sort order="ascending" select="name"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="country">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 {$svg-width} {$svg-height}" width="{$svg-width}px" height="{$svg-height}px">
        <g id="bar-chart" font-size="16" transform="translate(20,100)">
            <!-- place adapted code of existing template match="country" here -->
        </g>
    </svg>
</xsl:template>
```

This way you generate a different svg-image for each country. You may have to fiddle  with $svg-width, $svg-height and coordinates. On the other hand, managing coordinates gets easier because the diagram for each country starts always at the top of the image. This will not work out of the box, but it gives you the idea how to solve your problem.